# Why I cannot import a module?

Tags: haskell

Hello everybody

I cannot understand why I get such error when I try to import a module after I have imorted a Data.Char library?
Actually when I delete **module Test where** everything works correctly

[image]

```
import Data.Char
module Test where

sayHello = putStrLn "Hello, world withoutCorona!"

lenVec3 x y z = sqrt ( x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 + z ^ 2 )

sign x = (if x > 0 then 1 else 0) + (if x < 0 then -1 else 0) + 0


twoDigits2Int x y = if isDigit x && isDigit y then digitToInt x * 10 + digitToInt y else 100
```

Thanks in avance

Comment: You import after defining the module, so it should be `module Test where` and then `import Data.Char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Haskell program is a set of modules. A module is [structured gramatically as](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/modules.html#module-implementations):

> ```
> module     ->   module modid [exports] where body
>     |   body
> body    ->   { impdecls ; topdecls }
>     |   { impdecls }
>     |   { topdecls }
> modid   ->   conid
> impdecls    ->   impdecl1 ; … ; impdecln    (n>=1)
> topdecls    ->   topdecl1 ; … ; topdecln    (n>=1)
> ```

The `import` declarations are the `importdecls` in this grammar, and thus part of the `body`. A module can exists without a `module modid …` part, but if we define a module identifier, then this *precedes* the `body`.

You thus write such module as:

```
module Test where

import Data.Char

-- …
```

Answer (score 7):

Imports go after the `module`, not before. `module Name where` should be the first thing, possibly preceded only by language extensions and compiler flags:

```hs
module Test where
import Data.Char
```